# Cinebench R23 error prompt when running from command line

Tags: scripting, benchmarking, cinema-4d

I'm running a script which is exectuing various benchmarks, including [Maxxon Cinebench](https://www.maxon.net/de/cinebench).
I have been using Cinebench R20 so far, but now both Cinebench R20 and R23 shall be excecuted sequentially.

But when I run Cinebench R23 from within my script (Python) or from the command line with
`start /b /wait "parentconsole" Cinebench.exe g_CinebenchCPU1Test=true`, R23 will at some point show the following error message and won't terminate until it was closed:

> The external renderer is calculating an image. Do you want to stop it?

[image]

When I start Cinebench R23 from the command line without any arguments and click the Start button manually, the test runs without this message. I've downloaded R23 directly from the website, re-downloaded multiple times, tested with/without root privileges, on different PCs, but the behavior is always the same.

Has anybody had similar issues or knows a workaround/solution?